# GDB produce ?? symbols for segmentaion fault on ubuntu

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, gdb, debug-symbols

I am trying to debug my c++ programming assignment application using gdb on an Ubuntu server, because it produces segmentation fault.
But the file produces ?? symbols that are unreadable to me when I try `bt` it gives me.

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f141956d277 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007ffc1a866bd0 in ?? ()
#2  0x000055e1f101d5e0 in ?? ()
#3  0x00007ffc1a866db0 in ?? ()
#4  0x000055e1f1433e70 in ?? ()
#5  0x00007ffc1a866bd0 in ?? ()
#6  0x000055e1f10224a9 in ?? ()
#7  0x000055e1f14341f8 in ?? ()
#8  0x00000001f14344d0 in ?? ()
#9  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

I was following this [link](https://jvns.ca/blog/2018/04/28/debugging-a-segfault-on-linux/), and it told me to load these symbols

```
symbol-file /path/to/my/binary
sharedlibrary
```

The `sharedlibrary` was found, but the symbol-file path is not there. So,it did change `bt` command output somehow

```
(gdb) bt
#0  tcache_get (tc_idx=0) at malloc.c:2943
#1  _GI__libc_malloc (bytes=19) at malloc.c:3050
#2  0x000055e1f10224a9 in ?? ()
#3  0x000055e1f14341f8 in ?? ()
#4  0x00000001f14344d0 in ?? ()
#5  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

I still don't understand the bug.

Now, I don't know it's a problem from the GDB for not having this `symbol-file` or its a compilation problem which I don't know how or that's enough for me to debug, but I was following [Debugging a Segmentation Fault](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/troubleshooting-debugging-techniques/debugging-a-segmentation-fault-4QCUS) and it was much clearer to troubleshoot.

When I search for similar cases, all of them were answered only for their case, not a general solution how to deal with these kinds of error. I also thought of installing or locating that symbol-file but I didn't understand how.

If someone could help me, I need to understand what is my problem and how should I fix it.

Note: core dump is produced in the `/tmp` not in current application directory

Comment: Are you compiling with `-ggdb3` ? Typically this will produce an executable with the debug symbol that gdb requires. You may also want to reduce the optimization, removing `-O3` or similar, to make the assembly map more directly to your source code.

Comment: I don't know how to add them .. I just compile with this command `./Application testcases/singlefailure.conf `

Comment: Oops it was my fault not including the application file location while running this `gdb -c core Application` it showed some of my code except for line `#1` views `in malloc.c` and when I use `up` or `list` it produces the same. what this means?

Answer (score 0):

> I was following this link, and it told me to load these symbols

Don't follow this link (it's unnecessarily complicated for your use case).

Instead, do this:

```
gdb /path/to/my/binary
(gdb) run
```

... GDB will stop when your program encounters `SIGSEGV`

```
(gdb) bt     # should produce meaningful output now.
```

Comment: I don't understand what `/path/to/my/binary` refers to, I don't have this directory on my pc. Is it something should I install ? and how do I ? @EmployedRussian

Comment: The `/path/to/my/binary` is the same path you used in `symbol-file` command. It is the path to your binary, the one that you run, the one that crashes with segmentation fault.